# How to apply lambda function in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning how to use lambda functions in for loop and faced with this

```
l3=['one','two','three']
for i in l3:
    lambda i: i.upper()
    print(i)
```

I expect that each member of my list will be in uppercase but output is the same in lower case. What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: You're not calling the lambda, that's what you're doing wrong.

Comment: nor are you setting the lambda to anything to call it from

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How lambdas work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394483/how-lambdas-work)

Comment: Lambda *expressions* are just one way to define functions; there's nothing particularly special about a function defined by a lambda expression.

Comment: Did you mean: `map(lambda i: i.upper(), l3)`? Otherwise it doesn't make much sense to use a lambda at all, you can just do `[i.upper() for i in l3]` or `for i in l3: print(i.upper())` (depending on what you are actually trying to achieve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as others comment, you are printing the variable i and not calling at all the lambda

try instead:

```
x = lambda i: i.upper()
print(x(i))
```

Comment: Thank you i understood my mistake

Answer (score -1):

You're defining a lambda but you're never calling it. What you probably meant is

```
l3 = ['one','two','three']
for i in l3:
    i = (lambda x: x.upper())(i)
    print(i)
```

or

```
l3 = ['one','two','three']
for i in l3:
    f = lambda x: x.upper()
    print(f(i))
```

Which are not good examples on how to use a lambda anyway.

Also, notice that I'm calling the parameter `x` instead of `i`, since that `i` inside the lambda wouldn't be the same `i` you're using to iterate the list.

Comment: Thank you. Now i understand my mistake